# Xamarin Forms ProgressBar Not Fill Whole Screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I'm adding a progress bar to my project, I wanted to circular but can't find a good one. Anyway, I added xamarin forms native progress bar. It shown a little, I want it fill from left to right and vertically centerred.
[image]

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
              
                <ProgressBar IsVisible="{Binding ProgressVisible}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Progress="{Binding ProgressBarProgress}" x:Name="prgBar" ProgressColor="Aqua" />
               
            </StackLayout>
```

https://www.paste.tc/aktarimpagexaml This is my whole page code. How can i fix this ?

Comment: StackLayout only uses as much space as needed. Replace `StackLayout` with `Grid`. Then use `RowDefinitions` to divide the screen height, as desired. If you get stuck, come back and add to question an UPDATE section, with the revised code. You can have the complete code in a link, but ALSO put into the question enough xaml (as copy/pasted text) to see the structure, the Grid with its RowDefinitions, and each use of `Grid.Row="..."`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ToolmakerSteve, I fix this yesterday and update my code now.

Comment: The updated code works? Wonderful! If so, please *remove* it from question, *add it as "Your Answer"* below. This makes it more obvious that the question was answered.

Comment: ProgressBar located top of the screen but its fine. It fills left to right whole screen for all devices. User can understand somethings are loading at this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I updated my code like this. I make a new parameter name WidthReq and bind it to progressbar WidthRequest="{Binding WidthReq}". WidthReq is calculated to be suitable for all devices.

```
public double WidthReq { get => widthReq; set { widthReq = value; 
OnPropertyChanged(); } }
void getDeviceInfo()
    {

        // Get Metrics
        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
        //HEIGHT
        var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
        // Screen density
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
        Console.WriteLine("DEVICE WIDTH : " + width + " DEVICE HEIGHT :"+ height + " DEVICE DENSITY : "+ density);

        var mywidthrequest = (width / density) * 0.9;
        WidthReq = mywidthrequest;

    }
    
     <StackLayout  >

                <ProgressBar  IsVisible="{Binding ProgressVisible}" WidthRequest="{Binding WidthReq}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Progress="{Binding ProgressBarProgress}" x:Name="prgBar" ProgressColor="Aqua" />
               
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.

Comment: Thanks  Guangyu Bai, I accepted my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add the `Orientation` in the StackLayout.

```
<StackLayout>
      <ProgressBar  HorizontalOptions="Fill"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  x:Name="prgBar" ProgressColor="Aqua" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: https://www.paste.tc/aktarimpagexaml this is my whole code, how can i fix this ?